# Localizing Ruby alphabet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I'm working on I18N for a web application (Rails), and part of the app needs to display a select containing the alphabet for a selected locale. My question is, is there a way to get Ruby to handle this or do I need to go thru the Rails-provided I18N API?

This is the array I'm using for generating the select options:

```
'A'.upto('Z').to_a.concat(0.upto(9).to_a)
```

I need to translate that to Russian, Chinese & Arabic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an HTML `select`, with all the letters of a particular alphabet?

That would theoretically work for Russian and Arabic, but Chinese doesn't have an 'alphabet'.

The writing system contains [thousands of characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_characters#Number_of_Chinese_characters).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to implement this yourself. Afaik Rails i18n plugins don't provide this information.

A nice solution would be to creating you own Range.
Example from the docs:

```
class Xs # represent a string of 'x's
  include Comparable
  attr :length
  def initialize(n)
    @length = n
  end
  def succ
    Xs.new(@length + 1)
  end
  def <=>(other)
    @length <=> other.length
  end
  def to_s
    sprintf "%2d #{inspect}", @length
  end
  def inspect
    'x' * @length
  end
end

r = Xs.new(3)..Xs.new(6)   #=> xxx..xxxxxx
r.to_a                     #=> [xxx, xxxx, xxxxx, xxxxxx]
r.member?(Xs.new(5))       #=> true
```